# how to print one string object without set newLine() manually using TextPrinter

Tags: java, printing

Continuing my post for [finding the print service application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899225/print-service-on-java-web-application), I'm really interested in java4less(textprinter).  How do I to print one string object with multiple line inside, let's say the string name is out:

```
AID                     :   000922
A/C Number              :   XXXXXXXXX
A/C Name & Address      :   REKENING ANTARA SHB DGN TOP UP
```

Is it possible for using some function to put it once?  Without I must set it manually:

```
printer.printString ("AID                     :   000922");
printer.newLine();
printer.printString ("A/C Number              :   XXXXXXXXX");
printer.newLine();
```

Comment: PS: Instead of bolding code, indent it 4 spaces (select it and click the 1010 icon)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
printer.printString ("AID : 000922\nA/C Number : XXXXXXXXX\n");
```

The `\n` at the end should print a newline.

Comment: mark, I put this 
AID                     :   000922 \n
A/C Number              :   XXXXXXXXX \n
A/C Name & Address      :   REKENING ANTARA SHB DGN TOP UP \n

in one string object called "out", including \n, so the object will be shown like above.

but when I put that object like this printString(out); I cannot 
get the desired printing, only first line will be printed.

Comment: Hrm... then I dunno. `\n` is the newline character, but I guess `textprinter` doesnt know how to wrap it properly, so it just cuts ot off. Sorry for the useless post, I have no idea.